# How was distance measured when sailing the Liedenbrock Sea?

Tags: journey-to-the-center-of-the-earth

In [Journey to the Center of the Earth  (1877) by Jules Verne](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Journey_into_the_Interior_of_the_Earth).

The professor estimates the size of the sea to be 30 - 40 leagues.

> "How long do you suppose this sea to be?"
>
> "Thirty or forty leagues; so that we have no time to lose, and we shall set sail to-morrow."

Somehow the professor was able to estimate their speed.

> In an hour my uncle had been able to estimate our progress. At this rate, he said, we shall make thirty leagues in twenty-four hours, and we shall soon come in sight of the opposite shore.

From my understanding of [sea navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation) the process is rather complex, and without known stars, how was the professor able to track speed and/or position on the Liedenbrock Sea?

Comment: Could he keep sight of any fixed landmarks? perhaps on a cavern roof?

Comment: The sky is described in [Chapter XXX](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Journey_into_the_Interior_of_the_Earth/Chapter_XXX) It reads to me as if the ceiling of the cavern is not visible.

Comment: Maybe he used a [Chip log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_log) to estimate the speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the professor was simply measuring distance after that first hour and not concerned with directional navigation.  One possibility would be take a 'measurement' of some object on the departing shore that would be expected to be visible after traveling some distance.  The professor takes another 'measurement' of the object after an hours traveling.  The 'measurement' obviously wouldn't be precise, could be something like 'the number of arm lengths that span that boulder width'.  The professor, given the apparent size of the object after an hour at sea could roughly calculate the distance traveled which gives speed since he also has time traveled.  I assume the professor (being a smart fellow) has the necessary educational background providing him with the necessary math.